# Firefox dispatchEvent doesn't propagate to children

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, svg, firefox

I have an `<svg>` with a `<g>` with children, that have `pointerdown` event handlers, and a `<use>` referencing the `<g>`.

In Chrome if I register the event handler before I add the `<use>`, the `<use>` handles events like `<g>` and its children does. However in Firefox it doesn't.

To solve this, I added an event handler to the `<use>`, that dispatches a pointerdown event, that has `clientX` and `clientY` set (keeping in mind the different position of the `<g>`), on the `<g>`.

When I click on the `<use>`, my test event handler on `<g>` got called but the event handler of the children didn't, so apparently it didn't propagate.

Why is that? If you need more details, please ask me.

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you could put the actual HTML/JS code in the question, instead of just describing it

Comment: Could be [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1458481). Gard to tell without an actual testcase in the bug though.

Comment: Thank you so far. I will add code snippets later. Oh this at least explains why the event listener of `<g>`s children don't work under `<use>`. But this still doesn't explain why my alternative solution doesn't work in Firefox but in Chrome does.